# Why is Quinine more soluble in an acidic aqueous solution than an basic aqueous solution?

Tags: organic-chemistry

How do I find out if Quinine or in general if a compound is more more soluble in an acidic aqueous solution than an basic aqueous solution?

Here is the structural formula for quinine:

[image]

Comment: Investigate the properties of amines. This ? may be marked down without some effort on your part.

Comment: Observe whether a compound has basic centres. The protonated form has a much greater chance of being water souble.